# 2 differents Readers to fill an item in the same step

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have this situation. I have a csv file with some information, I have to complete this information with a database table registers ad write a new file with these info.

I guess that I should use a MultipleReader implementation, one to read my file and other to read my database (Some like this example: https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/09/15/spring-batch-multiple-sources-as-input/) But I need pass conditions to te query in relation a the current item being processed.

Any way, If it is possible, I need configure a query data in my reader2 with info getted in my reader1. How I could make this?

This a little resume of my problem:

```
Input File (Reader1)
Id;data1;data2;data3

Database (Reader2)
Id|data4;data5;data6

Output File
Id;data1;data2;data3;data4;data5;data6
```

Sorry My english. Any link to articles or docs is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common pattern known as the "driving query pattern" and is described in the [Common patterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders) section of the reference documentation.

You can use a `FlatFileItemReader` to read your input file and an item processor to query the database for the current item and enrich it with additional data.

Another idea is to load your flat file in a staging table in the database and use a database item reader to join data.

Comment: In my case, I think that driving query pattern is a good choice. Thanks!